# Disable display of field names in Django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

I intend to accept the values for the fields in my form from the user. However, I wish to have a common heading in the first row on the page for all of the rows (since the user will be adding multiple rows). I need help with telling django to not show the field name to the user and only show the textarea for entering the value.

How do I disable the display of the field name that is being shown in the form?

Comment: What are you using now? A simple `{{ form.field }}` will usually display only the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my models.py, I added the verbose_name field and set it to blank.

```
field1 = models.CharField(max_length=512,verbose_name="",)
```

This ensures that the field name:field1 is not shown when the form is displayed.

Comment: You can also set `label=''` in your form field definition.

Comment: I disagree with this. It goes against MVC. The verbose name should describe the field. If you want the form to look different, you should render it in the way you want, not by changing the characteristics of the field itself. Down the road, you might want to make another form that uses the full name, but it will be more difficult because the field won't have a real verbose_name.

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         {% for field in form %}
            <th>{{ field.label }}</th>
         {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
      {% for field in form %}
          <td>{{ field.widget }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```